# Returning JSON array to ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm getting stuck here.

I'm trying to trigger ajax when a div is selected and then get a JSON response. All I've been able to return is the error code, and I'm not sure why. Here's the simplified version (still getting same response as the actual). Maybe there's a better way? Thanks for your help.

jquery:

```
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
  #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
  #selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
  #selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
  #selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
</style>

<script>

  $(function(){


$("#selectable").selectable({
  selected : function(event, ui) {
    if($(ui.selected).hasClass('ui-widget-content')){
         var rptID = ($(ui.selected).val());
             $.ajax(
   {

      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "hello2.php",
      success: function( response ) 
      { 

        alert(1);
      },
      error: function( error )
      {
        console.log(error);


      }

   } );




    } 
    }
});

});
  </script>

  <body><ol id="selectable">
  <li class="ui-widget-content" value=1 >Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content" value=2>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-content" value=3>Item 3</li>
</ol></body>
</html>
```

php:

```
<?php
 $json = array('hello' => 'hello');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($json); 
 ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove the header line in the php file?

Comment: `alert(response):` maybe?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Are there error in browser console?  F12

Comment: Doesn't make a difference.

Comment: This is what I'm getting in the console: Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}

Comment: So error callback is called. can you put this:  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
} //and show what is logged in console.

Comment: Is this `php?>` in `echo json_encode($json); php?>` actually part of your code? If so, change it to `echo json_encode($json); ?>`

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, that's a typo. Thanks, though- I'll fix it.

Comment: You're welcome; just checking ;)

Comment: You could take a look at the network tab of your debugger and see the actual request and response.

Comment: @Brewal - In the network tab, I'm getting {"hello":"hello"} for the php page.

Comment: @SSA - when I used that error: function, I got this message: parsererror 
SyntaxError {stack: (...), message: "Unexpected token <"}
 Any idea where the < is coming from?

Comment: Whoa, I just deleted all the <html> and <body> tags in the code, and suddenly it works. Thanks @SSA! That's a useful tool :)

Comment: Great. Pay attention to Marc B's answer. He explained it why your were getting Unexpected token < error.

Comment: Sort of- I never actually had 'php?>' in the code- that was my typo on the question. It was an html tag in the php page that apparently caused the error.

Comment: Get rid of the closing `?>` if you're only responding JSON you don't need it and will get rid of spaces at the end of your script errors. Also do you get the type of the response as `application/json` in the Developer's Network tab?

Answer (score 3):

`php?>` is going to cause a syntax error/warning at the PHP level, and that syntax error output will probably get tagged onto the end of your JSON output, causing a JSON parse error on the client.

PHP code blocks are simply `<?php ... ?>`.

e.g.

```
[marc ~]$ cat z.php
<?php
echo json_encode('foo');
php?>
[marc ~]$ php z.php
"foo"PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant php - assumed 'php' in /home/marc/z.php on line 3
```

edit --- and now I see OP's edited away the `php?>` stuff...

Comment: I had made [`a comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387275/returning-json-array-to-ajax#comment39593627_25387275) to that effect (prior to your answer); OP responded afterwards saying it was a typo. I didn't even get a +1 for that and you got 2 lol - Now you need to edit your answer.